# Syntax error in 'as', is it about import?

Tags: python, django

I copied and pasted powerball model [from GitHub](https://github.com/PeterBorah/ethereum-powerball) in order to make powerball website.

But it doesn't work with error message that invalid syntax in last one

```
(as=rng, outsz=6)
```

What should I do to fix it? Is it error about `import`? Should I install other packages?

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings, BaseSettings
from django.utils import timezone
import random

from .rng import random_numbers, _sort
from .eth_tools import address, Contract

def buy_ticket(first,second,third,fourth,fifth,powerball):
 if msg.value >= self.config.ticket_cost:
    if block.number <= self.config.lottery_deadline:
        id = self.config.next_id

        if self._validate_ticket(first, second, third, fourth, fifth, powerball ) != 1:
             return(-3)

        self.tickets[id].owner = msg.sender
        self.tickets[id].numbers[0] = first
        self.tickets[id].numbers[1] = second
        self.tickets[id].numbers[2] = third
        self.tickets[id].numbers[3] = fourth
        self.tickets[id].numbers[4] = fifth
        self.tickets[id].powerball = powerball

        self.config.next_id = id + 1

        return([id], 1)
      else:
        return(-2)
 else:
    return(-1)

def check_winners():
    if (block.number <= self.config.lottery_deadline):
        return(-1)
    elif self.config.winning_numbers[0] != 0:
        return(-2)
    else:
        winning_numbers = self.config.rng_address.random_numbers(as = rng, outsz =  6)

    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        self.config.winning_numbers[i] = winning_numbers[i]
        i += 1
    i = 0
    while i < self.config.next_id:
        self._calculate_result(i)
        i += 1

    self._calculate_jackpot_results()

    return(winning_numbers, 6)
```

Comment: include the full error traceback.

Comment: please, don't use parentheses around returned values...

Answer (score 5):

`as` is a [*reserved keyword*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) (as part of the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), an `except` handler in a [`try` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), or an [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)); keywords can't be used as names.

Use a different name; a common approach is to add a `_` after the name:

```
self.config.rng_address.random_numbers(as_ = rng, outsz =  6)
```

However, the [code you copied](https://github.com/PeterBorah/ethereum-powerball/blob/48f5d887620c64f3a857468eec26db3de3a8a690/contracts/lotto.se#L72) is **not Python code**:

> "Powerball"-style lottery ***written in Serpent***, for prophetx's bounty.

(Bold italic emphasis mine).

And, from the [*Serpent Builder's Guide*](https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/serpent_features.html):

> Serpent is one of the high-level programming languages used to write Ethereum contracts. The language, as suggested by its name, ***is designed to be very similar to Python***[.]

It will fail on other issues too; all the files have `.se` extensions, not `.py` extensions, to indicate this is a different programming language. There are a lot of similarities with Python, but there are *more differences* that can't just be ignored. Use the [serpent compiler](https://github.com/ethereum/serpent) instead.